# Which regex can execute login and password

Tags: powershell

I have string connection to azure. I write powershell script which execute login and password from connection string. I don't want use substring.Can you help me with regex?

```
$stringConnection="Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Test;User ID=test@xxx;   Password=P@SSw0rd;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
$login=[regex]::Match($stringConnection,"???").Value
$password=[regex]::Match($stringConnection,"???").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? There are a lot of regex-tutorials available. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

Example: http://regexr.com?38ft1

Answer (score 0):

I did this way:

```
$stringConnection="Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Test;User ID=test@xxx;   Password=P@SSw0rd;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
$r = [regex] "Password=(.*?);";
$match = $r.match($stringConnection)
$login = $match.groups[1].value
```